# Decompose set into elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

Given a list of tuples where one element is a set:

```
{{{}, "a"}, {{1}, "a"}, {{2}, "a"}, {{3}, "a"}, {{1, 2}, 
  "a"}, {{1, 3}, "a"}, {{2, 3}, "a"}, {{1, 2, 3}, "a"}}
```

Which is the function that decomposes the sets into new tuples, repeating the other element in the tuple, i.e.

```
{{{{}, "a"}}, {{{1}, "a"}}, {{{2}, "a"}}, {{{3}, "a"}}, {{{1}, 
   "a"}, {{2}, "a"}}, {{{1}, "a"}, {{3}, "a"}}}
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = {{{}, "a"}, {{1}, "a"}, {{2}, "a"}, {{3}, "a"}, {{1, 2}, "a"}, 
   {{1, 3}, "a"}, {{2, 3}, "a"}, {{1, 2, 3}, "a"}}

Thread[{List /@ # /. {} -> {{}}, #2}] & @@@ lst // Column
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Tuples[{List /@ # /. {} -> {{}}, {#2}}] & @@@ lst
```

> same result

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you want:

```
expr /. {
   idxs_ : {__Integer},
   el_
   } :> ({{#}, el} & /@ idxs)
```

where `expr` is your expression.